# I want to get date in given format but this gives me output as 2020-03-65 15:23 instead of 2020-03-05 15:23,what is wrong with the code?

Tags: java

```
public class CurrentDateTimeExample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
    }
}
```

//code is provided above that I used to format date

Comment: `DD` stands for day-of-year. Use `dd` instead for day-of-month. For more, check [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: And you should switch to `yyyy` as well unless you're sure you want `YYYY` = week-based-year. It might cause weird things in the last days of a year.

Comment: Date code is always a pain, I have a bunch of helpers with a ton of unit tests for dates.  I seem to add them to every project I work on